# Share settings between VS 2015 to 2013

Tags: visual-studio

I have to downgrade from VS 2015 to VS 2013.

How can I export my settings to a lower version of visual studio? When I try do do a normal import from VS 2013 I get the error`"unsupported version"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to manually edit your .vssettings file, and change the ApplicationIdentity setting from 13.0 to 12.0. (On the second line, I think)

```
<ApplicationIdentity version="12.0"/>
```

Comment: I did, I get `Error 1:  Import was interrupted by the user´